# Yellow Messenger Chatbot issue

Tags: android, angular, apk, chatbot

We are using YM chatbot
Need to show icon on the screen. Its default position is right bottom of the screen.
Icon is hiding some functionalities

Icon is movable on web view but not on APK /mobile screen